# how to give title in flutter to pdf file before save to download folder?

Tags: flutter, dart, directory, save, title

I want exactly this page in flutter[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where that screen is coming from. But you can try the [file_picker_writable](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker_writable) plugin. (shameless plug).

```dart
  Future<void> _openFilePickerForCreate() async {
    final rand = Random().nextInt(10000000);
    final fileInfo = await FilePickerWritable().openFileForCreate(
      fileName: 'newfile.$rand.codeux',
      writer: (file) async {
        final content = 'File created at ${DateTime.now()}\n\n';
        await file.writeAsString(content);
      },
    );
    if (fileInfo == null) {
      _logger.info('User canceled.');
      return;
    }
    final data = await _appDataBloc.store.load();
    await _appDataBloc.store
        .save(data.copyWith(files: data.files + [fileInfo]));
  }
}
```

this will open a folder chooser dialog for the user and a default file name (given by `fileName`).

This code example will open the following dialog:

[image: Save dialog]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have this sorted, but I had similar problem and my solution was the following

```
class PdfPreviewPageProd extends StatelessWidget {
  final ProdutoData produto;
  final List<ItensProdutoData> itens;

  const PdfPreviewPageProd(
      {Key? key, required this.produto, required this.itens})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Ficha Técnica de produto'),
      ),
      body: PdfPreview(
        pdfFileName: produto.prodNome,//<- this is the sugested file name
        build: (context) => pdfFichaTecnicaProd(produto, itens),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```